# Why is my algorithm to find the total amount of unique integers in a subarray (contiguous), not working for larger amounts of Integers and subarrays?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashset, arraydeque

My algorithm to find the maximum number of unique integers among all possible contiguous subarrays doesn't work for larger amounts of Integers and subarrays.
For instance, I have to read a total amount of **6** Integers from the console and each subarray has a size of **3**.
So, for this kind of input 5 3 5 2 3 2
 my program should print **3** and this works fine.
The first subarray stores 5 3 5 so the number of unique Integers is *2*.
The second subarray stores 3 5 2 so the number of unique Integers is *3*.
The third subarray would also print *3* because it stores 5 2 3 and so on...

But, it seems like my algorithm can't handle a total amount of **100000** Integers with a subarray size of **99877**.
Can anyone explain me, what I have done wrong?
FYI: I have to use a Deque implementation like LinkedList or ArrayDeque

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalAmountOfIntegers; i++) {

    int anyIntegerNumber = consoleInput.nextInt();
    arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers.addLast(anyIntegerNumber);
    hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.add(anyIntegerNumber);

    if (arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers.size() == sizeOfEachArrayDequeAsSubArray) {

        if (hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.size() > quantityOfUniqueIntegersInSubarray) {
            quantityOfUniqueIntegersInSubarray = hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.size();
        }

        int firstNumberInDeque = arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers.remove();
        if (hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.size() == sizeOfEachArrayDequeAsSubArray) {
            hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.remove(firstNumberInDeque);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you remove the values from the hashset (or reset it)? You currently just count the distinct values up to the n'th element (always from the absolute first), and never remove any element from the hash. It has nothing to do with using larger sizes. Your current sample should also give a wrong result 3 for the last subarray `(2 3 2)`. Same for e.g. "1 2 3 1 1 1" (with subsize 3).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should also remove elements from my HashSet variable hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers. Would it be better to remove every iteration one element, or reset my hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers after each iteration?

Comment: Well, since you do not know how many "2"s there are in the hashset itself (which is the whole point of your hashset - though you might want to test a hashmap instead), you have to count it, e.g. by counting the number of "2"s in "arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers" if you are supposed to remove a "2" from both variables. Or reset the hash each time and refill it from "arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers" (see mumpitz's answer, it does exactly that). The first method is faster, but the second way is more straight forward and easier reusable in other situations.

Comment: And just so that we know what you mean by "all possible subarray":  For a main array of 1,2,3,4,5,6, you mean the elements 1,2,3, then 2,3,4, then 3,4,5  and so, not any three-element combination you can build, e.g. 1,2,3; 1,2,4; 1,2,5; ... ; 2,4,6; ... and so on, right?

Comment: Yes, what I meant with "all possible subarray" the elements 1,2,3, then 2,3,4, then 3,4,5 and finally 4,5,6

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be simply the unique integers in the whole array, since the array is the superset of all subarrays, all numbers would be present in it 
Just find how many unique element exist

Comment: Yeah, so to find how many unique elements exist in one subarray, I have created an HashSet variable. I named it hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers, but it seems like it doesn't work on a larger scale.

Comment: why do you need a dequeue for this? just simply use a hashmap, add the element to it, if it doesn't include the element increase ans by 1.

Comment: It is a challenge, where you are supposed to use a Deque

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, i don't understand your algorithm. I don't really get what the variables are referring to (although they seem to be named in a semantic way).
But what about this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UniqueIntegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UniqueIntegers ui = new UniqueIntegers();

        Integer[][] integers = {
                {3,5,3,4,6},
                {1,6,3,2,4},
                {2,3,4},
                {3,3,6,9,2}
        };

        Set<Integer> unique = ui.uniqueIntegers(integers);

        System.out.println("Unique Integers: " + unique.size());
        System.out.println("Integers: " + unique);
    }


    private Set<Integer> uniqueIntegers(Integer[][] ints){
        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (Integer[] iSub : ints){
            for (Integer i : iSub){
                result.add(i);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
Unique Integers: 7
Integers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

Comment: The problem is I have to use an ArrayDeque. I am looking for an improvement for my code.

Comment: OK i misunderstood what you meant by "sub arrays". I thought you where talking about multi-dimensional arrays. But isn't the number of unique integers among all the sub-arrays the same as the number of unique integers in the whole, initial array?

Comment: No, unfortunately, this isn't so easy. Let's say you have an array of 5000 numbers and a subarray size of 10. There could be 100 or 5000 distinct numbers. But each subarray can only hold 10 numbers. Maybe one subarray consists of [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2] or [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3]

Comment: So you have to take a look in each subarray and which one holds the total amount of distinct numbers.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of researching, I have found my mistake.
My third IF-Statement is wrong. I am comparing, if the size of my HashSet variable is equal to the maximum size of elements each subarray can hold.
Instead, I should compare, if my **int** variable **firstNumberInDeque**, which I remove first from my ArrayDeque variable, contains another **int** variable with the same value. So if this is true, my HashSet variable remains unchanged.
But, if my ArrayDeque variable doesn't contain another **int** with the same value of **firstNumberInDeque** than **firstNumberInDeque** should be removed from my HashSet variable.
Here is the right code:

```
int firstNumberInDeque = arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers.remove();
if (!arrayDequeToStoreAllIntegers.contains(firstNumberInDeque)) {
    hashSetToStoreUniqueIntegers.remove(firstNumberInDeque);
}
```